# Multiple select for aleady joined table

Tags: oracle

Below is a part of my select query. In the same query I am selecting `COLUMN_1` from a table `TABLE2` with condition check. Also I am joining this table at end with one of the condition in the inner select as below. Can we have any other way to handle this situation with out using multiple `SELECT inside.

```
SELECT 
    T1.COLUMN_1
    , (SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN_22 ='A' AND COLUMN_11=T2.COLUMN_11)
    , T1.COLUMN_2
    , (SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN_22 ='B' AND COLUMN_11=T2.COLUMN_11)
    , T1.COLUMN_3
    , (SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN_22 ='C' AND COLUMN_11=T2.COLUMN_11)
    , T1.COLUMN_4
    , (SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN_22 ='D' AND COLUMN_11=T2.COLUMN_11)
    , T1.COLUMN_5
    , (SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN_22 ='E' AND COLUMN_11=T2.COLUMN_11)
    , T1.COLUMN_6
    , (SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN_22 ='F' AND COLUMN_11=T2.COLUMN_11)
FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2  
    -- plus two more tables
    --plus some other conditions
WHERE T1.COLUMN_11=T2.COLUMN_11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE` instead:

```
SELECT T1.COLUMN_1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T2.COLUMN_22 = 'A'
            THEN T2.COLUMN_1
        END
    ,T1.COLUMN_2
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T2.COLUMN_22 = 'B'
            THEN T2.COLUMN_1
        END
    ,T1.COLUMN_3
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T2.COLUMN_22 = 'C'
            THEN T2.COLUMN_1
        END
    ,T1.COLUMN_4
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T2.COLUMN_22 = 'D'
            THEN T2.COLUMN_1
        END
    ,T1.COLUMN_5
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T2.COLUMN_22 = 'E'
            THEN T2.COLUMN_1
        END
    ,T1.COLUMN_6
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T2.COLUMN_22 = 'F'
            THEN T2.COLUMN_1
        END
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COLUMN_11 = T2.COLUMN_11;
```

**EDIT**

I changed the query to use the ansi join syntax.  But that change is irrelevant to what you are asking.  You can keep your join syntax if you want.  The only relevant change is in the `SELECT` portion of the query.

Comment: But with this solution you'll only have one T2.COLUMN_1 result.

Comment: @eyp: not sure what you mean. I'll I know is that I'm preserving OP's intent.

Comment: Yes, you're right... I also misread the query... with those similar names that has the original query is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have very clean solutions I think. Another possibility is with an inner join by case:

```
SELECT 
T1.COLUMN_1,
T2_1.COLUMN_1,
T1.COLUMN_2,
T2_2.COLUMN_1
T1.COLUMN_3,
T2_3.COLUMN_1
T1.COLUMN_4,
T2_4.COLUMN_1
T1.COLUMN_5,
T2_5.COLUMN_1
T1.COLUMN_6,
T2_6.COLUMN_1
FROM TABLE1 T1 
     INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2_1 ON T1.COLUMN_11=T2_1.COLUMN_11 AND T2_1.COLUMN_22 = 'A', 
     INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2_2 ON T1.COLUMN_11=T2_2.COLUMN_11 AND T2_2.COLUMN_22 = 'B', 
     INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2_3 ON T1.COLUMN_11=T2_3.COLUMN_11 AND T2_3.COLUMN_22 = 'C', 
     INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2_4 ON T1.COLUMN_11=T2_4.COLUMN_11 AND T2_4.COLUMN_22 = 'D', 
     INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2_5 ON T1.COLUMN_11=T2_5.COLUMN_11 AND T2_5.COLUMN_22 = 'E', 
     INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2_6 ON T1.COLUMN_11=T2_6.COLUMN_11 AND T2_6.COLUMN_22 = 'F', 
WHERE 

etc...
```

Comment: What?, this query is doing several inner joins with the same table, so there aren't two different values in the same column. Look at the aliases

Comment: Yes, I know it's hard to read, but there isn't a clean answer with those table names and what he wants to get.